# Run Tools without DLL Files - Visual Basic 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-media-player

I have a Windows Media Player with my application. And when I debug, it gives me some other dll files with the program, and it would be a pain in the butt to carry those files around with me. How would I get rid of these but keep my Windows Media Player implemented to the program? Is their a way I can add this to the project files or something? If not does anyone know any other good media players?

Comment: you need to provide us more information. Whats the name of the DLL's? What is the name of your media player ? Is it Microsoft Windows Media Player ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're trying to say is that you want to compile your external DLL's into your executable so you can deliver one .exe file. Unfortunately this is not something easily done.

I found this post: http://www.developerfusion.com/code/4504/merge-an-exe-and-a-dll-into-one-exe/ where you have to use the program ILMerge to do it.

Comment: The steps their are really complicated! Can you show me what I have to change, and what I don't?